# TypeScript: TypeScript requiring 'readonly' for private fields in class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, private

I'm working on a TypeScript project where I have a vector class. I've defined a private `#dx` field to keep track of the dx value value. However, TypeScript is warning me that the `#dx` field "Field can be readonly".

I supposed that there is some logic behind that, that conform with TS strict style.
But can't understand how, because OOP principles generally suggest to avoid directly getting/setting properties from outside, which can be enforced by making field private.
But how that's related to readonly properties - idk

But it doesn't warn me if i use `private` keyword that accomplishes same goal (although with some differences).

Here is the code:

```
class Vector {
    // warning 'Field can be readonly' here
    #dx: number;
    constructor(dx: number) {
        this.#dx = dx;
    }

    get dx() {
        return this.#dx;
    }
}
```

Can this warning be turned off globally somehow from tsconfig file maby?

Comment: Your code didn't give my any errors

Comment: the compiler knows that you only assign it a value in the constructor so it gives that "weak" level warning that it can be made readonly.

Comment: @pcalkins Ah yes, you are right. Even in full version of my class with methods like multiply, instead of setting dx dy, i was returning new Vector instances (which i am not sure is correct), and never was setting dx dy

Comment: The TypeScript compiler does not produce such a warning.  Maybe it's your IDE (and that IDE is using something other than IntelliSense to generate that message)?  This isn't reproducible unless you provide more information (if it's webstorm-specific, you should mention that and tag it)